# Content Navigator with CSS3 issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement something like [this Demo-2](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ContentNavigator/index2.html#slide-main).
Now my problem is when I click on [this, only index2.html](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ContentNavigator/index2.html), it don't load Demo-2 by default. I want to load Demo-2 immediately when index2.html load. I am new in CSS3 & I don't know how to make it work. Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying..

Comment: @SurjithSM Actually Demo-2 load when I click on Demo-2 button, but I want to load on page load.

Comment: you forgot to append `#slide-main` to the url: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ContentNavigator/index2.html#slide-main

Comment: You dont need to copy entire thing. just copy what you want. No need of that tab

Comment: yES, But i want to load any one navigation on page load, but it is not loading.

Comment: @abhitalks, that's the problem I want url as http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ContentNavigator/index2.html which gives output just as shown in http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ContentNavigator/index2.html#slide-main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Not sure this will work.

```
<body onload='location.href="#slide-main"'>
```